# maven-surefire-plugin return exit code: 0

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

I try to pass variables from the parent pom to the property file. The var is for some test in the java code.
I use maven-surefire-plugin with systemPropertyVariables. (see below(
But when I run "mvn install" the build fails end I get Exit Code: 0

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
      <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
          <VarName>VarValue</VarName>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: Im try to pass the variable to the property file, this is just the parent pom.

Comment: Sorry, but could you please edit the question, and say exactly what you did, what you get and what you expected to get? I cannot follow your explanations so far.

Comment: I edit my question, I hope It clear now

Comment: No, unfortunately not. How do you define the variables? What is the output of the Maven build? Your question needs to be at least twice as long.